# Scaling SVG past unknown threshold causes elements to disappear

Tags: ios, internet-explorer, svg, safari, openseadragon

I'm using openseadragon with the excellent [svg overlay plugin](https://github.com/openseadragon/svg-overlay).

On Chrome, the app behaves as expected: users can tap to zoom in until a table rendered in SVG is fully visible, the note on the table is legible.

[Here's the link to the demo](https://thewaves.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html). Zoom out to see the SVG version of the table appear, overlaying the fuzzy raster version of the background.

On Safari on iOS or OSX when zooming past a seemingly arbitrary threshold the table and everything on it start to disappear. The point of disappearance seems to depend on other factors I don't understand, hence this question for insight. For example, a orange circle drawn with two.js will disappear when the scale transform is precisely 51201 (at 51200 the circle is there). [image: screenshot of svg transform attribute]For the more complex table SVG, elements on the table will disappear at different scale levels, between ~23000 to 50000. Sometimes they'll disappear and then reappear upon a slight zoom in. Sometimes they'll disappear on zoom and then reappear as I pan around, the objects nearing the edge of the viewport.

IE 11 has a very similar issue.

Has anyone dealt with this before or solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really slick project!

In my experience, that kind of problem with SVG disappearing has to do with extreme amounts of zoom. The good news is you should be able to work around it by changing your viewport coordinates. By default the width of the image is a viewport value of 1, but you can set your image to be width 10,000 or some such, which will look exactly the same on the screen, but it means that the SVG thinks it's zoomed out a lot at first, so when you zoom in you can go a lot further.

If you're using two.js, another possible fix would be to switch over to canvas rendering and use https://github.com/altert/OpenSeadragonCanvasOverlay.

Btw, I'd love to share your project when it's done... please file a ticket at https://github.com/openseadragon/site-build/issues when you're ready and we can add it to http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/in-the-wild/.

Comment: Awesome! That works. Updated fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/detarmstrong/a5jhjf4g/7/)

Comment: Looks great! Do share the final piece when you've got it all together... I'd love to add it to http://openseadragon.github.io/examples/in-the-wild/